# How to set-up GDB debugging in IDA Pro on Linux via Wine?

Tags: ida, debugging, linux, gdb, wine

I tried running on linux via root terminal:

```
gdbserver --multi localhost:23947
```

And then at IDA Pro at Wine I use Remote GDB debugger with my local ip and port:

[image: IDA PRO GDB settings]

However when I start debugging I think registers receive wrong values:

[image: IDA at debug session]

Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm running latest version of Opensuse Tumbleweed and IDA PRO 6.6 x64 Win32 under Wine.

Comment: You will likely need to talk with support@hex-rays.com